# PhoneGap/Cordova: cannot prevent scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, phonegap

I have done everything possible to prevent scrolling in my PhoneGap (Cordova) app, but I just cannot prevent it. Here's what I've tried:

**`config.xml`**

```
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

**`index.html`**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' gap:; style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; frame-src *">

...

<style>
    html, body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

**`index.js`**

```
function ready () {
    document.body.addEventListener ("touchmove", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault ();
    }, false);
}

document.addEventListener ("deviceready", ready, false);
```

Literally nothing is working. Any ideas why not? Thanks!

Comment: are you compiling your app or using the Phonegap Developer app?

Comment: @jcesarmobile I am compiling from the PhoneGap CLI using `phonegap build android`.

Answer (score 1):

I put my app in a div and provided these rules to prevent scrolling. Not sure why applying the rules to `<body>` didn't work though. (In Cordova, but I'm confident this will work for PhoneGap)

```
.app {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
text-align:center;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: This was a while ago, so I solved it at the time by using an `iframe` (not an ideal solution). I don't know if your suggestion will work, so I won't accept the answer but I'll give in an upvote. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah i saw it was months ago, I just found the question while having the same issue so popped my solution in  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
element.ontouchmove = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I'm actually already doing this on `document.body` if you look at the last part of my question.